# pandas replace issue with dataframe

Tags: pandas

I create a dataframe by reading it from csv. The I filter the timestamp and got a new copy of dataframe, tried to replace the year 2019 to 2018 in new dataframe, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
ranks = pd.read_csv("/tmp_file.csv")
print(ranks)
mask=(ranks["Date/Time"] > pd.Timestamp(start_time)) & (ranks["Date/Time"] < pd.Timestamp(end_time)) & (ranks["Op/sc"]>100) 
df = ranks.loc[mask]
print(df)
df.replace(regex=r'2019.*$', value='2018', inplace=True) 
print(df)
```

Ranks:

```
        Date/Time        Rank  Op/sc
0 2019-03-18 03:07:57     0      6
1 2019-03-18 03:08:12     0      5
2 2019-03-18 03:08:27     0      4
3 2019-03-18 03:08:42     0      4
4 2019-03-18 03:08:57     0      7
```

df

```
            Date/Time       Rank  Op/sc
25    2019-03-18 03:14:12     0    160
26    2019-03-18 03:14:27     0    103
27    2019-03-18 03:14:42     0    129
32    2019-03-18 03:15:57     0    119
```

df after replace

```
             Date/Time       Rank  Op/sc
25    2019-03-18 03:14:12     0    160
26    2019-03-18 03:14:27     0    103
27    2019-03-18 03:14:42     0    129
32    2019-03-18 03:15:57     0    119
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert column `Date/Time` to datetimes first:

```
ranks = pd.read_csv("/tmp_file.csv", parse_dates=['Date/Time'])
```

Then convert strings to `Timestamps` are not necessary:

```
mask=(ranks["Date/Time"] > start_time) & (ranks["Date/Time"] < end_time) & (ranks["Op/sc"]>100)
df = ranks[mask].copy()
```

And last for replace year `2019` to `2018` use:

```
mask1 = df["Date/Time"].dt.year == 2019
df.loc[mask1, "Date/Time"] = df.loc[mask1, "Date/Time"] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
```

If all years are `2019` filtering is not necessary:

```
df["Date/Time"] = df["Date/Time"] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
```

EDIT:

```
mask1 = df["Date/Time"].dt.year == 2019
df.loc[mask1, "Date/Time"] = df.loc[mask1, "Date/Time"].iat[0]
```

Comment: try:  df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'] + pd.DateOffset(years=1)

Comment: @GustavoGradvohl - I think Op need subtract, answer was edited. Thank you for idea.

Comment: Sorry, I think I mislead you, my purpose is to replace the column of timestamp to a specific one.

Comment: @Ping - Can you explain more? Do you need replace all datetimwes with year `2019` to value `2018`? Like `mask1 = df["Date/Time"].dt.year == 2019` and `df.loc[mask1, "Date/Time"] = 2018` ? But then get mixed values - datetimes with integers

Comment: @Ping - yes, it is expected, because your code replace strings, not datetimes.

Comment: @Ping - Can you edit question? Because bad comments formatting.

Comment: @jezrael I want some thing like below.
1. filter those data between start_time and end_time.
2. Replace all the time in the filtered data to start time. For example: all the 2019-xx-xx xx:xx:xx to 2019-03-18 02:07:57